# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project jraft: No license for governance

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, travis-ci, license-key

I'm trying to setup SonarQube.com on travis for a maven project, but I see the following exception on build:

```
[INFO] User cache: /home/travis/.sonar/cache
[INFO] Load global settings
[INFO] Load global settings (done) | time=456ms
[INFO] User cache: /home/travis/.sonar/cache
[INFO] Load plugins index
[INFO] Load plugins index (done) | time=16ms
[INFO] Download sonar-scm-cvs-plugin-1.0.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.3.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-plsql-plugin-2.9.0.901.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-csharp-plugin-5.8.0.660.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-java-plugin-4.7.1.9272.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-web-plugin-2.5.0.476.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-flex-plugin-2.3.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-xml-plugin-1.4.2.885.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-vbnet-plugin-3.0.3.346.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-swift-plugin-2.0.0.1127.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-python-plugin-1.7.0.1195.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-github-plugin-1.4.0.699.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-cfamily-plugin-4.6.0.7071.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-auth-github-plugin-1.3.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-rpg-plugin-2.1.0.736.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-scm-mercurial-plugin-1.1.1.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-googleanalytics-plugin-1.1.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-widget-lab-plugin-1.8.1.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-pli-plugin-1.5.0.702.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-javascript-plugin-2.21.0.4409.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-groovy-plugin-1.4.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-cobol-plugin-3.3.1.1636.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.2.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-php-plugin-2.10.0.2087.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-abap-plugin-3.3.jar
[INFO] Download sonar-governance-plugin-2.0.0.1789.jar
[INFO] Download qualinsight-sonarqube-badges-3.0.1.jar
[INFO] SonarQube version: 6.3.0
[INFO] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:42 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-03T09:47:20+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 70M/468M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar (default-cli) on project jraft: No license for governance -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Here is the `.travis.yml`:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

addons:
  sonarqube:
    organization: ${SONAR_ORGANIZATION}
    token:
      secure: ${SONAR_TOKEN}

script:
  - ./travis.sh

cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.m2/repository
    - $HOME/.sonar
    - $HOME/jvm
    - $HOME/maven
```

Here is the `travis.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

INITIAL_VERSION=1.0-SNAPSHOT

export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1G -Xms128m"

mvn package sonar:sonar \
  $MAVEN_ARGS \
  -Dsonar.host.url=$SONAR_HOST_URL \
  -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN \
  -Dsonar.projectVersion=$INITIAL_VERSION
```

Why I am seeing this error `No license for governance` as I am not using any commercial sonar component (only sonar-java I suppose)?

The problem seems to be related to the fact that one of the plugins needs a commercial key, but How I can tell Travis to only install the java plugin?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Still, I see on your repository (https://github.com/dzlab/jraft) that you did not follow the Maven-based projects available in the "Get Started" guide (http://about.sonarqube.com/get-started/). Any reason?

Comment: OK, I found your problem, see my answer below.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam thanks for your feedback, but I don't see you answer!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a look at your repository, you should not override the various parameters that the Travis Add-on is specifying for you.

More specifically, when you override `SONAR_TOKEN` on the Maven command line (at [line 12](https://github.com/dzlab/jraft/blob/master/travis.sh#L12)), the consequence is that the token that you have encrypted and passed at [line 11](https://github.com/dzlab/jraft/blob/master/.travis.yml#L11) of your `.travis.yml` file is completely wiped out. Because of this, your analysis is run like if you were anonymous.

So please follow the [Get Started](http://about.sonarqube.com/get-started/) guide and simply run the following Maven command:

```
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent package sonar:sonar
```

Comment: Thanks after removing all the additional params in the mvn call the build works!!!

Comment: why in sonarqube source they are setting additional parameters to the maven sonar plugin  https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/travis.sh#L147-L152

Comment: Because they are not using the Travis Add-on

Comment: Ah indeed !! thnx

Answer (score 0):

sonar-governance plugin is commercial plugin.
check [here](https://www.sonarsource.com/why-us/products/plugins/governance.html)

```
.....
[INFO] Download sonar-governance-plugin-2.0.0.1789.jar
......
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the below works from my jenkins pipeline

```
node{
   stage 'Code Quality'
   sh "mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://<hostname>:9000"
}
```